# Unclear on why "as" is necessary in Angular "async" pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, pipe

I have the following markup in my HTML. It works as supposed to and performs according to the expectations.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="stuff$ | async as data">
  <div *ngFor="let element of data">{{element.name}}</div>
</ng-container>
```

I started to tamper with it to see what I can brake/improve so, assuming that the *as data* only assigns a variable name to the resulting outcome of subscription (due to *async* pipe), I hoped that I can reuse *data$* directly, without going about the extra variable. So I changed to this.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="stuff$ | async">
  <div *ngFor="let element of stuff$">{{element.name}}</div>
</ng-container>
```

This failed miserably, producing the error below.

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

While I understand the sense of the error, I don't see where it's coming from. The service that I subscribe to returns an observable of an array. Is the *as*'ing of the property being *async*'ed mandatory? I'm sure there's a subtle, little thing I missed when I was reading up on the asynchronous pipe but I'm failing to see it.

```
stuff$: Observable<Thing[]>;
ngOnInit() { ...
  this.stuff$ = this.stuffy.getStuff();
}
```

Comment: Why did you think that *would* work? You're effectively replacing a reference to the value returned by a function with a reference to its argument, they may not even be the same type.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I can't motivate for this particular case. However, in my 20 years of playing with programming, I've been in a situation where I **didn't think** something would work, yet it did. Numerous times. In the weirdest ways imaginable (at least to me). So, although I didn't actually think it would work this time, the statistics told me that I might be wrong again. Does it make sense?

Comment: To a certain extent, but in the absence of a reason to think it would work and given unambiguous feedback that it indeed does not, it's not clear to me why you were left with a question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I see where you're coming from. It's pure humbleness, I guess. There **was** a likelihood that the approach producing the error message actually **was correct** but hidden behind another, obscure error. It was a long shot but if you imagine that I'm not as bright as others, then it calls for not only establishing ***that** it doesn't work* but also for explaining ***why** it doesn't work*. And I was too ignorant to achieve that. Trust me, I wouldn't waste my time (nor others') if I was able to explain sufficiently reliably the intricate specifics of the observed phenomenon. :)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think one of the comments just proved my point. I simply was too dumb to figure out the following syntax myself: *let item of stuff$ | async*. But it was that approach I was trying to achieve (omitting the intermediate *stuff* declaration to pick *item* elements from). My apologies for being insufficiently eloquent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's simple: `stuff$` contains an observavle. When you use the `async` pipe, behind the scenes angular subscribes to the observable and return it values to be used on the template.

When you use `as data` it will save the result of `stuff$ | async` to the `data` variable, allowing you to use it without needing to use the `async` pipe multiple times.

Your second code fails because you can't iterate over a Observable, since it's an object.

Comment: So the only way to ever get my paws on the outcome of the subscription is to *as* it into something? If so, is there ever any case, however weird it might be, when we won't need *as*'ing but can work with the pipe, hmm... *as*'lessly?

Comment: Yes, but it will be less efficient.

Comment: @KonradViltersten there are plenty of cases to use the async pipe without 'as', ie in ngFor where the result is your iterable: `*ngFor="let item of items$ | async"` or input bindings: `[input]="observable$ | async"` or just if you're really looking for a true false: `*ngIf="show$ | async"`

Comment: @bryan60 Oh, oh, oh, **there** it is! I just got the raisin in the cake. I was aiming for the very first of your examples - letting the iteration assign elements from an *async*'ed observable. I just failed to think of that syntax due to lack of success while thinking, haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you could just do this:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of stuff$ | async">{{element.name}}</div>
```

ngFor is designed for this.

Comment: I'm split now. On one hand, @EliasSoares did answer the question as it was formulated. He did so correctly and graspably. On the other hand, you figured out what my ducking issue was, suggesting a pragmatic re-approach to my question, the actual question. So his answer is correct. Yours is useful. I can't decide which I should put my greeny-checky on. What do you think?

Comment: doesn't matter to me. there are still cases to not use async in your ngFor directly and still use an 'as', such as if you want a different display if the list is empty.